# How to make <Navigator>'s navigationBar locate at the top?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator

I want my NavigationBar be able to persist across scene transitions so I am using the `navigationBar` props of `<Navigator>`. ([Official Navigator doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html))

When I pass `<ToolbarAndroid>` into `<Navigator>`'s navigationBar props, `<ToolbarAndroid>` will locate on the bottom of the screen (below renderScene)

```
<Navigator
      initialRoute={ routes[0] }
      renderScene={ this._routeMapper.bind(this) }
      configureScene={ () => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid }
      navigationBar={(
        <ToolbarAndroid
          title={"Nav Bar"}
          titleColor="#ffffff"
          navIcon={require('../img/ic_menu_white_48dp.png')}
          onIconClicked={ this.props.onIconClicked }
          style={styles.toolbar}
        />
      )}
```

[image]

I guess that's because `<Navigator>` renders navigationBar after renderScene.

Although I can set ToolbarAndroid's position to absolute and top: 0, the renderScene will be covered by the Toolbar this way so it's not ideal.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

Or is there any other recommended way to implement the NavigatorBar which will persists across scene transitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can user nativigation bar in renderScene function inside `<View>` enclosed tag

for yor reference look through this link [react native movies app](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.android.js)

look line no `#48` to `#62` you will get a clear idea.

pass a route reference variable like id,name to identify which screen you want to render then add your nativigation toolbar.

Comment: Thank you @Anwar for sharing this method. However, I am looking for a solution that allow my NavigationBar to be able to persist across scene transitions.

If I place my navigation bar inside renderScene then it will be re-rendered every time I push a new scene :/